# Highcharts - How to start x axis from an arbitrary value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using [highcharts][1] to plot a graph between a range of values from data base. I want by X Axis values to start from the user input.

For example, if the user wants the values between range 50 and 100, I want my x axis to start from 50.

The range would be of variable size. The size of the data is large so I can't do something like getting all and using min and max for display.

Thanks in advance.

This is my chart object. I have two input fields for user that I use to query the database and return rows in between.

I use multiple type of graphs. The problem is that I have no idea on how to define the start of X axis as 50 if I am getting data from database between 50 and 100. It shows 50 values but start them from 0 upto 50.

I tried min 10 and so. That do start from that value but skips the first 10 or so values.

The input field has id 'lower' and 'upper'.

---

```
var options = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: ctn.attr('id'),
        type: $('#graph_type option:selected').val(),
        zoomType: 'x'
      },
      title: {
        text: $('#graph_title').val()
      },
      subtitle: {
          text: "Graph - " + (graph_no + 1)
      },
      xAxis: {

        title: {
           text: $('#x_label').val()
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: $('#y_label').val()
        }
      },

      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: []
    };
```

Comment: You should show us what you've already tried.

Comment: Like this? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947942/highcharts-how-to-change-x-axis-options

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the response. I found the solution. Min max was not actually doing as I wanted it to.

I found the solution.

To start the x axis value from desired value use

```
plotOptions:
     <your_graph_type>:{
             pointStart: <your_value>
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think setting min and max for xAxis will work.
[Refer this link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min)

and you can say

startOnTick: false,
endOnTick:false

For example refer  : [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nagoba/dP8cL/)

I have values set min of y to 20 and max to 217,

```
yAxis: {
        min: 20,
        max:217,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick:false
    },
```

See how ther chart is displayed.
I hope this helps.